# How to set selected option to default selected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, materialize

I have select option with materialize style, In select option I want to check a value of option is exist in database or not.

**HTML Code :**

```
<div class="row margin">
   <div id="input-select" class="section">
       <label>Supir</label>
          <select name="id_personalia" id="id_personalia" onchange="cek_supir()">
              <option id="default_supir" value="default_supir" disabled selected>pilih supir</option>
               <?php
                 foreach ($supir as $s) {
                ?>
                 <option value="<?= $s->id_personalia; ?>"> <?= $s->nama_ktp . " " . $s->id_personalia; ?> </option>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
          </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript code :**

```
<script>
function cek_supir() {
    var supir = document.getElementById("id_personalia").value;
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($stat_supir) ?>;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (supir == data[i]) {
            $("#id_personalia").val('default_supir');
            Materialize.toast('Supir sedang bertugas', 3500);
            //document.getElementById("default_supir").selected = true;
            //document.getElementById("id_personalia").selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the select option can't set selected option.

Comment: where is the jquery code?

Comment: `document.getElementById("id_personalia").value=data`

Comment: @guradio the code just like that, no more

Comment: @Rayon content of var data is json broo. but thank for the attention hehe

Answer (score 0):

The materialize select overrides the browser default, so when you change a value in `select` element, you need to update the component, using `.material_select()`:

```
function cek_supir() {
    var supir = document.getElementById("id_personalia").value;
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($stat_supir) ?>;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (supir == data[i]) {
            $("#id_personalia").val('default_supir');
            $("#id_personalia").material_select();
            Materialize.toast('Supir sedang bertugas', 3500);
        }
    }
}
```

See [docs](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select) for more info.

Comment: still not working, i have try using `$("#id_personalia").material_select();`

Comment: @AfganGanjar Some minutes ago, you say that was working. What happened?

Comment: i try in another case the code working properly, but when i try in this case the code is not working.

Comment: @AfganGanjar Check your JSON data and HTML markup. The selection code is correct.